# How to make an Expert advisor to enter a trade at an exact price?

Tags: mql4, trading

I made an EA, it is to enter trade at a particular price. But I notice it is not entering the trade at the exact price, it is entering the trade at price that is 3-5 fractional pips above the specified price. What I want is that the EA enters the trade at the exact price. Can someone help please?

Comment: Do you have anything to show? How you compare the doubles? Keep in mind that `0.1+0.2 != 0.3 if using floating dot values` Do you have same problem for both buys and sells, or only for buys (in such case you forgot about spread).

Comment: Thank you. am thinking it is because when the candle move very fast during news, it usually moves fast in 2-3 pips in which i want the  trade to enter, so it is not captured. Am also thinking that it is because of instability in the computer network, making the EA to go off for just some milliseconds in which pips have already gone by. correct me on what i just typed above. Am thinking if it is running on a VPS, where there is close to perfect stability in network, the EA will execute trade exactly at the price i specified. What do you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### How to make an Expert advisor to enter a trade at an exact price?

Making a trade is a bilateral contract - it has a side that offers you a price ( mediated by your Broker ) and it has a side ( you, in person or represented by an automated code-driven trading-agent ), who accepts a price. All regulated by Terms and Conditions signed / accepted for doing this business.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Rule#0: Prices move faster, than the QUOTE-message ever makes it to your CPU
// --------------------------
   RefreshRates(); // A MUST DO AS-LATE-AS-POSSIBLE, before placing a tight slippage XTO
// --------------- // A RE-TEST AS-FAST-AS-POSSIBLE if XTO conditions hold
   ...
// --------------- // GO / NO-GO XTO, always using Normalized values
   ticket = OrderSend( Symbol(),
                       XTO_OrderTYPE,
                       NormalizeDouble( XTO_volume, LotDigits ),
                       NormalizeDouble( XTO_price,  Digits() ),
                       MaxSlippage, //---------------------------- BE CAREFULL ON THIS
                       0,           // [XTO_price_SL]
                       0,           // [XTO_price_TP]
                       ordername,
                       MagNumber,
                       0,
                       clr
                       );
```

### Time matters, prices move indeed fast. VPS may avoid, but yet a part

Before we get to the type-of-Contract, which decides, how a trade is being executed on the Broker side ( a spot-Buy-Long uses other price-handling than a pending-BuyStop ), first, let's look at the network latency ( how long does the Top-of-the-Book [ToB] price hold, before it is changed and advertised from market to Broker and from Broker to your computer or to VPS computer ( even the best co-located VPS machines are a few hundred meters "farther" on the cable, and "behind" the Broker's machine, thus a few orders of magnitude slower in receiving ToB-QUOTE-updates, than your Broker Server is ).

The ToB-prices hold for way less than **`100 ms`** in steady markets on FX-Majors, yet there are ofter thousands of wild moves during fundamental events, where each **`[ms]`** may contain tens, if not hundreds and sometimes thousands ToB-price changes per `[ms]`.

[image]

If you insist on having an **exact price** for a trade, you may use but pending-contracts, not the immediate-price executed orders ( often called at-Market ).

### Your Broker Terms and Conditions define the rules for doing this.

Be aware, that even pending-orders may "acquire" a price-slippage, a difference between an "ordered"-price and actually "executed"-price, so again, Terms and Conditions will rule ( SNB flash-crash event was a Tsunami a few years ago, after many Brokers filed for bankruptcy and KMPG and other court-named supervising bodies were liquidating ashes from uncovered pendin-orders for many many years later ), so due Risk-Management is a must and never believe an optimistic assumption a trade-order will get filled at-an-exact-price. There are both technical and legally supported reasons, why this is not always obeyed even for the pending-orders.